# KIvy Android how to create and read a file

Tags: android, python, kivy

After looking all over google I haven't found a way of accessing Android internal storage from python.

I need to store an image generated by kivy app. I would like my python code to be able to navigate to a root user dir, create an app specific dir (if not found) and save the image there.

Simply creating a file with my device's path doesn't work. Should I be setting permissions for internal storage access? I'm lost with it.

Comment: What do you mean by your 'device's path'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something wrong in your code, you didn't paste the code nor logs, so... let's get it another way.

You can read/write with python just fine in the app folder (`/data/data/org.something`) with using:

```
app_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

To write to SD card you'll need to use [`App.user_data_dir`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir), which as you can see in the docs on android gets you `/sdcard/<app_name>`. Not sure if it automatically creates it if it's missing, so it needs checking out probably. However, if it doesn't exist, just create it with python:

```
os.mkdir(App.user_data_dir)
```